# boost.spirit: taking action on incomplete input stream

Tags: c++, boost

Would it be possible to use spirit to take action on an incomplete
stream? I want to make a command line interface for a program. For
example, a complete command sequence could look like this:

> processmanager process rouge kill

but say the user entered:

> processmanager process ? (or hit the tab key)

and I want to show a list of processes could I do this with spirit? If true please answer with an example.

Thanks

Comment: The Windows XP `taskkill`, with a verbose command structure, is pretty unusable compared to its predecessor commands where the user supplied the minimum info and did *not* have to memorize a silly complex command structure. Keep it simple, stupid. KISS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may, if you try hard enough, find a way to coerce boost.spirit into doing what you want to do. My initial thought on this was that you may be able to consume your tabs with a skip-parser and trigger printing out your list of alternatives from a semantic action on the tab character.

But I'd recommend avoiding boost.spirit here. I say this because debugging problems with spirit and other TMP-heavy libraries is hard to start with, when you're just using them for what they're intended for. This isn't something boost.spirit is intended to be used for, so attempting this will likely lead you to the nasty edge cases and leave you with something impossible to debug.